# Ordering a matrix to have the maximum value in each diagonal

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, confusion-matrix

I've looked around StackOverflow and other forums for a solution but am yet to find a solution that just uses Base-R - which is what I need to be using for this.

I'm trying to maximise the diagonal in an NxN matrix by row, so the maximum value from that row is on the diagonal (I hope this makes sense - specifically in the context of Cluster analysis)

So far, I have tried hard coding this but it feels counter productive - this was done by trying to create a 'swap' function, using a for-loop down the columns and swapping the required entries. 
i.e. on row 1:
1,3,4,7 -> 7,3,4,1
row 2: 
4,10,14,22 -> 4,22,14,10 
etc.

Here is an example of the matrix I would try to use:

```
CM <- table(expected, predicted)
CM
     1   2  3  4  
  A  11  1  0  66
  B  0   22 77 18  
  C  10  49 34 48  
  D  0   46 31 49  

#Desired:
CM

     1   2  3  4  
  A  66  1  0  11  #max 66
  B  0   77 22 18  #max 77
  C  10  34 49 48  #max 49
  D  0   46 31 49  #max 49
```

Here is an extract of the (awful) swap function which did not work.

```
swap <- function(x,y){
  a = c()       #create an empty vector
  a <- x        #assign x value to a (where x = diagonal location)
  x <- y        #assign y to x (where y = maximum value 
  y <- a        #re-assign a value back to y

}
```

above shows how I would expect the results - I was hoping someone could provide me with some useful pseudo code or to let me know if there is anything I have been missing out.

Sorry if this is an easy or obvious question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So looking at this, it seems that you want to loop over the matrix row by row and alter each row by swapping the max element with the element in the diagonal. My idea of how to do that is to use this swap function:

```
swap <- function(matrixRow,x,y){
  #x is diagonal index
  #y is max of the row
    indexY <- which(matrixRow == y)
    valX <- matrixRow[x]
    matrixRow[x] <- y
    matrixRow[indexY] <- valX
    return(matrixRow)
}
```

This would return the altered version of the row. Then you could assign this new version of the row to the current row. For example,

```
vals <- c(11,0,10,0,  1,22,49,46,  0, 77, 34, 31,   66, 18, 48, 49)
mat <- matrix(vals, nrow = 4)
```

Edit: woops hit the wrong key and it posted too early. here's the rest:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(mat)){
rowI <- mat[i,]
y <- max(rowI)
mat[i,] <- swap(rowI, i, y)
}
```

Comment: beautiful method, worked as expected and without issues.

Answer (score 2):

The prior way to do this is to implement the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

Just picking the maximum in each row does not necessarily maximize the diagonal, because the maximum in one row may be marginally better than the second best, while picking the second best will allow you to get a much larger value on another row.

Comment: Yep, I realised that my question didn't actually address what I wanted to do. Shame coding the Hungarian method without packages is very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the Hungarian Algorithm Suggestion for those using Python (I found this comment in a search for a Python solution.)

Here is a code snippet of the highest reordered matrix such that the diagonal has all of the best "clusterings".

y is the vector of true labels.

pred is the vector of cluster labels.

linear_sum_assignment is the Hungarian Algorithm.

-cm is to maximize, cm is to minimize.

contingency_matrix is a non highest diagonal ordering of the clusters actual to predicted.

The output shows the diagonal of a best case clustering just like a confusion matrix diagonal shows the "correct" predictions.

```
from sklearn.metrics.cluster import contingency_matrix as CM
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment
cm = CM(y,pred)
row_idx, col_idx = linear_sum_assignment(-cm) #-cm to maximize, o/w it minimizes 
print(cm[row_idx,col_idx])
```